# Input right values at x-axis

Tags: r

```
>a<-runif(10000)
>a

>b<-matrix(a,100,100)
>b[,1]=0
>b

>if(b[w,e-1]==1 & b[w,e]<1/3)b[w,e]=0 else if(b[w,e-1]==0 & b[w,e]<0.5)b[w,e]=0 else 
>b[w,e]=1 
>b


 n<-c(1:100)    # 'x value'

for(y in 1:100)
print(sum(array(b[,y]==0))/100)       #it prints 100 values but 'how can i use these values???'

plot(n, "??????")
```

I want to make a graph by R. but when i input this statement

```
plot(n, {for(y in 1:100) sum(array(b[,y]==0))/100 })
```

it didn't work well

Comment: please read the [Introduction to R](http://www.cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf); it will address such questions in a much more efficient manner. This type of question is not a good fit for Stack Overflow; here you need some basic familiarity with the language.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign the values to another variable and you should not use a for loop that way.

This is a really basic question and you should find the answer in any basic introduction to R.

In any case I am not really sure I understand what you want to get with your original code... (what's `b`, and why you are comparing it to 0?) but probably you want to use something along these lines:

```
x <- 1:100
y <- 3*x + 5
plot(x,y)
```

Comment: i think that you misunderstood my question..

Comment: Your example is not reproducible (it won't run as it is written, you don't define `e`). In any case you just need to put the result of your operation in a variable rather than print it. That was the point of my answer.

Comment: for(w in 1:100)
for(e in 2:100)

Comment: i didn't learn this program.. so i don't know how to put result of my operation in a variable :(

Comment: I wrote you an example... `x <- 1:100` puts the numbers 1 to 100 in x. `y<-3*x+5` puts the result of the operation `3*x+5` in y. Just substitute your operation and you are set. Then grab a basic introduction to R and read it, this would be covered in the first 10 pages.